# Modify "View" in admin panel for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, wp-admin, taxonomy, row-actions

Fristly, sorry for my bad english.
Secondly, I can't find a solution for my problem since 2 weeks. It's a simple things but I can't find how to do it.
I explain my problem :
I got 2 custom taxonomies call in a function "my_custom_init" :

```
register_taxonomy( 'directors', 'video', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Directors', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
register_taxonomy( 'clients', 'video', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Clients', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
```

I would like to edit the link "View" like on the print screen :
http://nsa32.casimages.com/img/2012/10/18/121018025542594841.png

I think I have to use the post_row_actions to edit it but I can't get the taxonomy.
If you know how to solve my problem, thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit**

I made this for my categories "post" and "video" and it works ! But I can't do the same for my custom taxonomies :/
I don't really understand I tried but doesn't work :S

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1);
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() === 'post' )
        unset( $actions['view'] );

    if( get_post_type() === 'page' )
        unset( $actions['view'] ); //doesn't work ?

    if( get_post_type() === 'video' )
        unset( $actions['view'] );

    // Adding a custom link and passing the post id with it
    $permalink = get_permalink();
    $permalink = explode(".tv", $permalink);
    $actions['customedit'] = "<a href=\"/#$permalink[1]\" target=\"blank\">View & Get Url</a>";

    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `directors_row_actions` & `clients_row_actions`.

Also you can use `tag_row_actions` which is called for every taxonomy. It accepts 2 parameters, first being the actions & 2nd being the term object. You can use this term object to filter out which actions you want to change

Comment: I made an edit on my post :)

Comment: did you try replacing `post_row_actions` with `directors_row_actions` & `tag_row_actions`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
 * Generates and displays row action links.
 *
 * @since 4.3.0
 *
 * @param WP_Term $tag         Tag being acted upon.
 * @param string  $column_name Current column name.
 * @param string  $primary     Primary column name.
 * @return string Row actions output for terms.
 */
protected function handle_row_actions( $tag, $column_name, $primary ) {
```

gives you 2 neat filters:

```
        /**
     * Filters the action links displayed for each term in the Tags list table.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @deprecated 3.0.0 Use {$taxonomy}_row_actions instead.
     *
     * @param string[] $actions An array of action links to be displayed. Default
     *                          'Edit', 'Quick Edit', 'Delete', and 'View'.
     * @param WP_Term  $tag     Term object.
     */
    $actions = apply_filters( 'tag_row_actions', $actions, $tag );

    /**
     * Filters the action links displayed for each term in the terms list table.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$taxonomy`, refers to the taxonomy slug.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string[] $actions An array of action links to be displayed. Default
     *                          'Edit', 'Quick Edit', 'Delete', and 'View'.
     * @param WP_Term  $tag     Term object.
     */
    $actions = apply_filters( "{$taxonomy}_row_actions", $actions, $tag );

    return $this->row_actions( $actions );
```